# Add component validation to avoid 'SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field' for grandchild

Tags: visualforce, soql, visualforce-component, relationships, rendered

I want to create a component that can accept an SObject without requiring it to have all of the fields displayed on the component. However, when trying to access a grandchild, I am not able to render based on `rendered="{!IF(grandchild__r==NULL,TRUE,FALSE)}"`.

Instead I get the error:

`SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: grandchild__r`

Is this possible without having to require all component fields to be queried in the page (or page controller) that are calling the component? I would also like to avoid creating a component controller if I can.

Comment: no if you want to refer then need to query or create new instance of object and then use that.

Comment: The issue is that your code causes the field to be checked in the existing query and that's what causes that error to occur. So, there's no way around it.

Comment: I didn't understand why you are using `__r` instead of `__c` here. Am I missing something? If you want to check if a reference is null, you can use `__c`.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I am using __r for something like grandchild__r.Name__c. The grandchild__c works fine and is not null but when i try to access grandchild__r I get the error. This render would be set up to avoid getting the error altogether. But it seems that in order to even do the comparison, the field must be in the query.

Comment: try `grandchild__r.size = 0` in your rendered expression; there's also a workaround if that doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to declaratively get grandchildren. The general rule is for Visualforce Pages and formula fields you can go "up" 5 relationships but only "down" one. So you either need to add an extension to query for the grandchildren or consider if you can refactor your page to accept the child as the object